# Lookup State name in GEOJSON file using coordinates

Tags: r, geojson, r-sf

I am receiving this error message in RStudio:

```
> Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) :
> Evaluation error: Found 3 features with invalid spherical geometry.
> \[2\] Loop 7 edge 5 crosses loop 10 edge 8
> \[36\] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 45 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
> \[39\] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 2 is degenerate (duplicate vertex).
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In st_is_longlat(x) :
> bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
> 2: In st_is_longlat(x) :
>
> Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) :
> Evaluation error: Found 3 features with invalid spherical geometry.
> \[2\] Loop 7 edge 5 crosses loop 10 edge 8
> \[36\] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 45 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
> \[39\] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 2 is degenerate (duplicate vertex).
```

I want to create a function that will locate the state name by inputting latitude and longitude coordinates. Here is my code:

```
library(sf)

.usstate.geojson <- sf::st_read("https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json/us-states.geojson")

find_state <- function(lon, lat, sp_polygon = .usstate.geojson) {
    res <- character(0)
  
    which.row <- sf::st_contains(sp_polygon, sf::st_point(c(lon, lat)), sparse = FALSE) %>%  
        grep(TRUE, .)
  
    if (identical(which.row, integer(0)) == TRUE) {
        res <- c(res, NA)
    } else {
        d <- sp_polygon[which.row, ]
        res <- c(res, paste0(d$name))
    }
    return (res)
}

find_state(39.7071, -98.6132)
```

So, latitude 39.7071 and longitude -98.6132 should return Kansas.

Comment: Try disabling s2 by using `sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)` .  And you probably want to swap those coordinates in `find_state(39.7071, -98.6132)` .

Comment: @margusl Thank you! Should I be concerned about the warning message?
`Warning message:`
`In st_is_longlat(x) :`
 `bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data`

Comment: As switching to some alternative shapefile / geopackage / geojson is so easy, I personally would just pick some other datasource. Added few to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`us-states.geojson`seems to have some non-valid geometries, while disabling s2 through `sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)` makes it kind of functional (at least for some queries) and `st_make_valid()` apparently fixes all but one ploygon, it might still a good idea to switch to some other dataset. E.g. `rnaturalearthdata::states50`, datasets from US Cencus or administrative units from GADM - https://gadm.org/data.html .

Lookup itself can also be simplified, one option is `st_filter()`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# alternative State datasets:

# sf complains about states50 too but is able to fix it
# .usstate <- st_as_sf(rnaturalearthdata::states50) %>% st_make_valid()

# https://gadm.org/data.html
.usstate.geojson <- read_sf("/vsizip//vsicurl/https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/json/gadm41_USA_1.json.zip")

# changed parameter order from lon,lat(x,y) to lat,lon
find_state <- function(lat, lon, sp_polygon = .usstate) {
  st_filter(.usstate, st_point(c(lon, lat)))[["NAME_1"]]
}

find_state(39.7071, -98.6132)
#> [1] "Kansas"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>